# Game vs. Stockfish, not sure what I did wrong

Tags: strategy

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qd6 4. Be2 Nc6 5. Nf3 e5 6. d4 Nxd4 7. Nxd4 Qxd4 8. Qxd4 exd4 9. Nb5 Bd6 10. Nxd6+ cxd6 11. Bf4 Bf5 12. O-O-O Rc8 13. c3 dxc3 14. Bb5+ Kf8 15. Bxd6+ Ne7 16. Rhe1 Be6 17. Bd7 cxb2+ 18. Kxb2 Re8 19. Bxe8 Kxe8 20. f4 g6 21. Be5 Rg8 22. Bf6 Nc6 23. Rd6 Kf8 24. Red1 Bd5 25. R1xd5 a6 26. Rd8+ Nxd8 27. Rxd8# null 28. Rxf8# null 29. Rxg8# null
```

In case you didn't guess from the winner, Stockfish was white and I was playing black. Also, I gave myself 10 minutes for the whole game, with no increment. I technically know what mistakes I made but would like some practical advice on how to actually avoid them while I'm playing; engine analysis can show you the lines after the game but that doesn't really help you improve that much as a chess player.

Comment: Your first mistake was playing the Scandi. From then on, there is no hope in beating StockFish ;)

Comment: Fair point. I wanted to play an opening that I didn't know at all so that I would be able to purely see how my playing strength was, without any opening prep to artificially inflate my apparent strength.

Answer (score 2):

Well, stockfish is too strong that Carlsen can't even compare, so don't worry.

In my opinion, before e5 you should calculate the variations with d4 and Nb5, and they did bring u problems.

Bd6 is really not a good choice. Black gave up his bishops. After the exchange on d6, white owns bishop pairs in a really open game, and the pawns on d-line are really weak.

Kd8 may get stuck by Bf4, but Bb4+ and Ba5 is great. Take the chance that white king in e1, and you can get a free move. if white Bd2, then Kd8 after the exchange is safe because there's no Bf4.

After the exchange on d6, stockfish just showed its extraordinary skills.

In the end: that's all my own opinions, and I checked it on stockfish before write the things above. I got fide rating 2000+.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I found it horrifying how long before the end Stockfish already had that M in the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

...Bd6 leads to catastrophic pawn weaknesses and loss of the Bishop pair.  But as that looks unavoidable without other concessions your mistake is earlier.
After 6.d4 you probably should play 6...a6 to stop Nb5.

Your position is still bad as you are well behind in development.  5...e5 looks too ambitious and you probably should have gone for Bg4 or Bc5 instead.